# JSON Buscar dados de páginas especificas

Tags: php, javascript

Olá! Estou tentando puxar dados de uma API que eu fiz em PHP para enviar em JSON para um outro site. Eu consegui puxar o resultado de toda uma tabela de funcionários, porém agora eu quero quando clicar em dos funcionários apareça os outros dados relacionados a ele como Telefone, endereço... puxando pela ID dele.

A API que faz a conexão da index.html

```html
<?php

require_once 'bd2.php';
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*');
$pdo = conectar();
$listar = $pdo->query("select * from funcionarios");
echo json_encode($listar->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ));

 ?>
```

O javascript que faz o JSON da index.html

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var container = $("#teste2");
  var lista = container.find("#lista");
  var html = '';

  $.getJSON('http://teste.com/api-home.php', function(data){
    $.each(data, function(k, v){
      html += '<p>Nome: '+v.nome+'</p>';
      html += '<p>E-mail: '+v.email+'</p>';
      html += '<a href="perfil.html?id='+v.id+'">Perfil</a>'
    });
    lista.html(html);
  });
});
```

A API do perfil que faz a conexão com o perfil.html

```html
<?php
require_once 'bd2.php';
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*');
$pdo = conectar();
$id = $_GET['id'];
$listar = $pdo->query("select * from funcionarios where id='$id'");
echo json_encode($listar->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ));

 ?>
```

O javascript que faz o JSON do perfil.html

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var container = $("#teste5");
  var lista = container.find("#lista2");
  var html = '';

  $.getJSON('http://teste.com/api-perfil.php', function(data){
    $.each(data, function(k, v){
      html += '<p>Telefone: '+v.telefone+'</p>';
      html += '<p>Endereço: '+v.endereco+'</p>';
    });
    lista.html(html);
  });
});
```

Comment: Se você usar assim: `$listar->fetchAll(3)`? O que acontece?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creio que falte passar o ID como **parametro** no javascript da página perfil.html.

Nesta parte da API do perfil você esta fazendo um **GET** para pegar o **id** e buscar o **funcionario** com este **id**.

```
...
   $id = $_GET['id'];
   $listar = $pdo->query("select * from funcionarios where id='$id'");
...
```

Porém no javascript da página perfil.html você **não** esta passando este **id**, como parâmetro sendo assim a sua API não vai conseguir fazer a consulta no banco.

```
...
   $.getJSON('http://teste.com/api-perfil.php', function(data){
...
```

Sendo assim quando clicar em um funcionário você precisa pegar o **ID** dele e passar junto a url da API do perfil:

```
...
   $.getJSON('http://teste.com/api-perfil.php?id='+ID, function(data){
...
```

deste modo quando o código da API for fazer o **$GET['id']** ele vai pegar o **id** que você passou junto a **url** e vai ter como buscar o funcionário pelo seu **id**.

Comment: Mt obrigado, era isso mesmo.